# Не получается запустить Qt Designer

Tags: qt, qt5

Не получается запустить Qt Designer. Выдает такое сообщение

> "please check your qt visual studio add in settings"

В Qt Options qtVersion - qtbase C:\Qt\5.6.0\qtbase

Comment: поищите на диске `designer.exe`

Comment: ничего не нашло

Comment: может, попробовать поставить версию Qt по старее? 5.4, 5.3?

Comment: visual 2015 стоит..

Answer (score 1):

Qt -> Qt Project Settings -> Version, не указана сборка Qt